# How to save a subdocument (embedded) with a reference in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this 2 mongoose schemas, the first is embedded in the second

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        minLength: 3,
        maxlength: 500,
        required: true
    },
}, {timestamps: true} );

const PictureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        minLength: 3,
        maxlength: 80,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [CommentSchema]
}, {timestamps: true} );

module.exports = mongoose.models.Picture || mongoose.model('Picture', PictureSchema);
```

Both schemas are in the same file. Note that both documents refer to another Schema called User. I am getting an error when saving:

```
const comment = new Comment({
    user: user,
    text: description
});

const picture = new Picture({
                user: user,
                title: title
});

picture.comments.push(comment);
await picture.save();
```

user is a user object from the other schema, I am confident it is good as previous to add the comments array it was working.

the error I am getting says **ReferenceError: Comment is not defined**

It looks to me that because I am including Picture like this

```
const Picture = require('../model/Picture');
```

it can't find Comment, but I tried putting them in 2 separated files and still not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you only have problem with module exports. To make `Comment` accessible from external file, you need to export it.

In the end of schema definition file use:

```
module.exports.Picture = mongoose.models.Picture || mongoose.model('Picture', PictureSchema);
module.exports.Comment = mongoose.models.Comment || mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

In the file where you use models use:

```
const { Picture, Comment } = require('../model/Picture');
```